# Linking gcc dynamically

Tags: gcc, build, static-linking

This is actually two questions:

1 - On my debian amd64 system, I can't seem to build a cross GCC dynamically linked with gmp/mpfr/mpc.  It always statically links them EVEN when I remove `--disable-shared`, which AFAIK is a target only option in a cross compiler?

2 - Why does everyone statically link gcc with these libraries?  I understand if you're bootstrapping a system why you would want it statically linked, but I do not understand why it is so common to see statically linked gcc...  My gut feeling is that it is wasteful to statically link gcc when it is possible to dynamically link it.  Is it?

Answer (score 0):

> It always statically links them EVEN when I remove --disable-shared

Shared = Dynamic

Static = Static

That is all.